# AppCompatDelegate.setApplicationLocales method do nothing in compose project (target api 33, activity inherited from ComponentActivity)

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I tried to implement a language picker in my app (target api 33) according to this official guide
[android app-languages](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/app-languages)

But when I call AppCompatDelegate.setApplicationLocales(appLocale) method nothing happens. And after some debugging, I figured out that when the code reaches getLocaleManagerForApplication() method in AppCompatDelegate.java class static member sAppContext is null during all method.

```
    @RequiresApi(33)
static Object getLocaleManagerForApplication() {
    if (sLocaleManager != null) {
        return sLocaleManager;
    }
    // Traversing through the active delegates to retrieve context for any one non null
    // delegate.
    // This context is used to create a localeManager which is saved as a static variable to
    // reduce multiple object creation for different activities.
    if (sAppContext == null) {
        for (WeakReference<AppCompatDelegate> activeDelegate : sActivityDelegates) {
            final AppCompatDelegate delegate = activeDelegate.get();
            if (delegate != null) {
                Context context = delegate.getContextForDelegate();
                if (context != null) {
                    sAppContext = context;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (sAppContext != null) {
        sLocaleManager = sAppContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCALE_SERVICE);
    }
    return sLocaleManager;
}
```

That's why method do nothing. I suppose that problem is that I inherit MainActivity from ComponentActivity, not AppCompatActivity. If I use AppCompatActivity I need to specify app compat theme in the manifest. But it is an entirely compose project. So how to fix this using ComponentActivity?

Comment: "If I use AppCompatActivity I need to specify app compat theme in the manifest" - I don't think that's true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to updated [Google documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/app-languages#androidx-impl) and the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74413010/17629065), you have to use an AppCompat theme in your manifest.

```
<application
    ...
    android:theme="@style/AppCompatTheme">
    <activity .../>
</application>
```

Then, if your project is entirely Compose, use a Material theme inside your Activity's `onCreate()`.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContent {
        MaterialTheme {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

}

I have an entirely Compose project with target API 33 too, and it works for me.